# Need to display mysql table data in specific format in HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I am stuck into a problem in PHP. Basically I need to show data fetched from mysql table in a HTML table in certain format. Am unable to figure out how I can do it. Below is my query and PHP code:

```
$array = array();

$query = mysql_query("select name, townid, entry_date from tbl_entry  where month(entry_date) = '02' and year(entry_date) = '2016' group by townid, name ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $array[$row['name']][$row['townid']]= $row['entry_date'];
}
```

With this, var_dump on $array variable shows correct mysql results that is expected. Here is the content of $array:

```
array (size=2)
  B => 
    array (size=2)
      3 => string '2016-02-16' (length=10)
      6 => string '2016-02-16' (length=10)
  A => 
    array (size=1)
      3 => string '2016-02-16' (length=10)
```

I need to display this in a HTML table in below format:

```
Serial Number | Date         |     A    |     B
-------------------------------------------------------
 1            | 2016-02-16   |     3    | 3     
 2            | 2016-02-16   |          | 6
```

Code tried so far:

```
<thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Sr No</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <?php
                        foreach($demo3 as $srid=>$array) {
                            $SRname = GetSingleRow(ADMIN,$srid);
                            echo "<th>".$SRname['name']."</th>";    
                        }


                    ?>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                    <?php 
                        $count = 1;
                        foreach($array as $key=>$val) {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>$count</td>";
                            foreach($val as $t =>$d) {
                                echo "<td>".$d[$t]."</td>";
                            }
                            echo "</tr>";
                            $count++;
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
```

But am not getting expected output. Please help me in this.

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'll consider it in further projects. Right now can't change in current one as am far ahead in this with mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try read somesthing about PDO — its improve ypu skills with DB work.
Try this code:

```
<?php
$rowArray = array();
foreach( $array AS $key => $val )
{
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $val AS $key2 => $val2 )
    {
        $rowArray[ $i ][ 'date' ] = $val2;
        $rowArray[ $i ][ $key ] = $key2;
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Sr No</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <?php
        foreach($demo3 as $srid=>$array) {
            $SRname = GetSingleRow(ADMIN,$srid);
            echo "<th>".$SRname['name']."</th>";    
        }


    ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
    <?php 
        $i = 1;
        foreach( $rowArray AS $row )
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $i . '</td>';
            foreach( $row AS $rowData )
            {
                echo '<td>' . $rowData . '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
            $i++;
        }
    ?>
</tbody>
```